# Scan Barcodes using Webcam in java

Tags: java, swing, barcode, zxing, barcode-scanner

I need to scan a barcode from the selected webcam so my program can run its code from the inputs.
The main problem is my lack of experience in java.

What I will need:

- A box in a JPanel showing the webcam view (so the operator can adjust the barcode for a good scan)
- When a barcode is found, an event is triggered that I can pick up on to run my code.
- Cross platform (Windoze, Mac & Linux)

ZXing looks promising, but I don't know how to use it. This is the hardest part of my project, so before anyone says I should start on something simpler, I just need to get this to work and then I can do all the other simple stuff ;)

Thanks.

Comment: Err... why don't you do all the other simple stuff first, then do this part afterwards?

Comment: not sure if you are trolling at the `Windoze` thing

Comment: @MarkByers Concurrency maximises throughput :p

Comment: @Adrian As can be derived from the first sentence, how does one scan a barcode with the given constraints?

Comment: Zxing is your best bet. What have you tried? What didn't work? Etc. Gotta give to get.

Comment: @SeanOwen ZXing seems to only take files. Would I need to grab the webcam view every few milliseconds, save it to file and then run ZXing on it? That seems rather inefficient to use a third party HDD.

Comment: Not at all. It can use a BufferedImage or anything else for which you can implement LuminanceSource

Comment: @SeanOwen Can you help me by example?